# Tendency to pronounce certain final consonants

Tags: phonétique

In French there exists a tendency to pronounce certain final consonants which are normally silent. To me this makes sense if there is a homophone so they want to distinguish two different meanings, as in *plus*: /ply/ and /plys/. I'm wondering about those cases where there are no homophones as in *ananas*: /ananas/ or *août* /ut/. Why do some French speakers pronounce  these final consonants?

Answer (score 2):

The /plys/ vs /ply/ (more vs no more) distinction is regular in French.

On the other hand, pronouncing the final *s* in *moin**s*** is very distinctive.

The tendency is to standardize on the "Parisian TV/Radio accent" but there are still significant regional variations.

See : [Ces mots qui ne se prononcent pas de la même façon d’un bout à l’autre de la France. Mathieu Avanzi](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/02/25/6999/):

[image: ananas]

Answer (score 1):

One reason that accounts for this phenomenon is simply that the speakers have been trained to pronounce them or not to pronounce them, their background (family, region, school) being responsible for this habit forming; this makes it clear that they've never worried about whether to pronounce them or not : they just followed a dominant trend ; this is why I personally always pronounce the t in « aout » ; I've heard it pronounced so very few times without a final t that I never got familiar with this alternative.